# Tsung load simultanoeus users in certain time

Tags: xml, xmpp, ejabberd, tsung

Is there any way to load users in tsung in certain time. To be clear I want to give an example. Lets say I want to load 2 simultenous users in every 6 seconds.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tsung will close the connection automatically. So you can not specify the number of concurrent user at the same time.

However, You may look into `thinktimes` property and before closing the connection you can increase the thinktime value.

So idea is you connect 1 user every 10 millisecond and keep the thinktime of 1 second. So in 1 second you are connecting 10 users..  Even if Tsung close the connection for 8 users within that time you will have at least 2 simultaneous users.